# Java - Returning Multiple Integers to an Array

Tags: java, arrays, integer, return

I am trying to return multiple integers to an array through a void. Something like this:

```
public class abc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] evenNumbers = { findEvenNumbers(0, 10); };

    }

    public static void findEvenNumbers(int min, int max) {

        for(int i = min; i <= max; i++) {

            if((i % 2) == 0) {

                return i;

            }

        }

    }

 }
```

I know that will produce quite a few errors, but is there a way I can return multiple integers to an array (sort of like the program above)? Thanks!

Comment: You really need to learn Java =\. It would be better to grab a book or an online tutorial. There are lot of recommendations on [StackOverflow Java wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info)

Comment: Sorry, little rusty from coming back to Java.

Answer (score 4):

This will do the trick, I think:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Abc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] evenNumbers = findEvenNumbers(0, 10);
        // should really do something with the result:
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(evenNumbers));
    }

    public static int[] findEvenNumbers(int min, int max) {
        int[] result = new int[max - min + 1];
        int n = 0;
        for(int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
            if((i % 2) == 0) {
                result[n++] = i;
            }
        }
        if (n < result.length) {
             result = Arrays.copyOf(result, n);
        }
       return result;
    }

}
```

Changes from your original code:

- Changed class name to start with upper case (Java coding convention; does not affect behavior).
- Changed `findEvenNumbers` to return an `int[]` instead of `void`.
- Changed initialization expression for `evenNumbers` to account for `findEvenNumbers` returning an array instead of an `int` value.
- Changed the body to store even numbers in array `results` and return `results` (after adjusting length).

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
public static void findEvenNumbers(int min, int max)
```

to

```
public static int[] findEvenNumbers(int min, int max)
```

this means you are intending to return something from the function (void means nothing will be returned). In this case, an array of ints will be returned.

create and return an array from the method like this:

```
int[] arr = new int[numberOfElements];
//put stuff in array like this:
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;

return arr;
```

Comment: You still haven't shown how to fill `arr` which is basically the hearth of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Noete: You cannot return anything from a function with void return type

```
   public static Integer[] findEvenNumbers(int min, int max) 
    {
       List<Integer> lists = new ArrayList<Integer>();

      for(int i = min; i <= max; i++) {

        if((i % 2) == 0) {

            lists.add(i);

        }         

    }
 return (Integer[])(lists.toArray());
}
```

Comment: This will generate a ClassCastException because `lists.toArray()` will return an `Integer[]`, not an `int[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
    private static ArrayList <Integer> evenNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void findEvenNumbers(int min, int max) {

        for(int i = min; i <= max; i++) {

            if((i % 2) == 0) {

                evenNumbers.add(i);
            }

        }
   }

   public static void main (String [] args){

       findEvenNumbers(0, 10);

       Iterator iterator = evenNumbers.iterator();

       while(iterator.hasNext()){

          System.out.println(iterator.next());
       }

   }
```

I recommend you to make classes which will make what you want instead of putting everything in the main class, where you have the main method :)